# L'Hôpital's full name

Tags: reference-request, math-history, mathematicians

I think we've all heard of L'Hôpital's rule when solving limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (for those doing calculus or real analysis at a higher level) but the other day my lecturer went through some interesting facts and background  about l'Hôpital (other common names: **Guillaume de l'Hôpital** or **Guillaume François Antoine, Marquis de l'Hôpital**).

I went to Google on his full name (since everyone said that that was the shortened version) and the closest that I got to was "**Guillaume-François-Antoine Marquis de l'Hôpital, Marquis de Sainte-Mesme, Comte d'Entremont and Seigneur d'Ouques-la-Chaise**", even still they mentioned that his name was longer.

So, what was his full name? (I couldn't find any from my searches on Google)

(I was thinking about this while taking a break from my real analysis tutorials :) )

Comment: His real name should be `L'Hospital`, with `os`, not `ô`. The rest is the list of his titles, just like Prince Charles is  Duke of Cornwall, Duke of Rothesay, Earl of Carrick, Baron of Renfrew, Lord of the Isles and Prince and Great Steward of Scotland.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Bernard Why should it be `L'Hospital`? In his book (see https://archive.org/details/analysedesinfini00lhos) his name is written as `de l'Hôpital`. So far I assumed both are fine but why is `L'Hospital` better?

Comment: The transformation `os > ô` before a consonant in French dates back to the 18th century,  after the death of the Divine Marquis…

Comment: This is how modern French write [marquis de L'Hôpital](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Fran%C3%A7ois_Antoine,_marquis_de_L%27H%C3%B4pital).

Comment: This is (quite contemporary) Fontenelle's [Eloge of *de l'Hôpital*](http://www.academie-sciences.fr/pdf/dossiers/Fontenelle/font_pdf/p125_136_vol3486.pdf)

Comment: Here is a later printing of his [textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=LtRUjcTSplAC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Bernard - the so-called "Divine Marquis" was [de Sade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquis_de_Sade#Title_and_heirs)... Maybe are you alluding of the "torture" implicit in e.g. computing an integral ?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: ‘Divine Marquis’ was only a private joke… As to the spelling, you also have the example of his (posthumous) [Traité des sections coniques](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1042799f). These examples show the transformation  `os > ô` had begun, but it had not, as far as I know, when he was born (second third of the 17th century).

Comment: See also the post : ["LHôpital's rule" vs "L'Hospital's Rule"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179680/lh%c3%b4pitals-rule-vs-lhospitals-rule)

Comment: See [Use of the circumflex in French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French) . "It often indicates the historical presence of a letter (commonly *s*) that has, over the course of linguistic evolution, become silent and fallen away in orthography."

Comment: The "modern" form is [hôpital](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%B4pital): "from Old French hospital", that appeared in 16th Century.